# Can you explain the classification report (Recall and Precision) on provided example?

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, confusion-matrix, precision-recall

Now I know that many have asked this question, however, I still do not quite understand the precision and recall score that sklearn library outputs. Here is the example output:

[image]

If possible could someone answer my question in the following manner using the simplest language you can muster:
- Precision 0.95 False means what for the model?
- Precision 0.56 True means what for the model?
- Recall 0.88 False means what for the model?
- Recall 0.76 True means what for the model?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different classes: True or False. Imagine that you have True as Apples and False as Oranges.

**Recall** is a metric that gives us insight about the **total** number of **correct** values retrieved with respect to the total number/size of your dataset/database.

So, imagine that you have a picture with 30 apples in it. Also, you have an object detection system, whose purpose is to identify/detect the apples within a picture.

Now, your object detection system draws 50 bounding boxes (rectangles in the picture), 30 around all your apples, and 20 also around some oranges that look like those apples.

**Recall**, in this case, given by the formula `TP / (TP + FN)` , i.e. true positives / true posivites + false negatives, is 1.0! Of course your recall is 1.0 (or 100% although statistically the correct values for precision and recall range between 0 and 1), because it detected all your apples!

Therefore, in your example `TP = 30, FN = 0` (no apple missed from the image). so `30/(30 + 0) = 1.0`

However, you are unsatisfied with your results, because even though your object detection system correctly identified all the apples in your image, it also considered that 20 oranges are apples.

Here comes the **precision** metric. Precision gives us insight about the already retrieved apples (not for the entire database like Recall does), and answers the questions: "Out of the already identified as apples, how many of them are exactly apples?"

One can easily see that precision penalizes the machine learning model for false positives, in our case the false positives being the oranges identified as apples.

In your case, you would have `TP /(TP + FP)  === 30  / (30 + 20 <---oranges considered apples))`

Therefore, your precision would be 0.6.

To sum up the explanation : recall gives hindsight with respect to the total numbers in the database

Recall answers the question: (provided that you have 30 apples) "out of these 30 apples how many do you retrieve/identify?").

Precision on the other hand is giving us information about the already retrieved "apples".

Precision answers the question: "Out of the examples already retrieved and considered apples, how many are in fact apples?"

Precision is tied to False Positives, while Recall to False Negatives.